# What happened to dead cells which still keep DNA information?

Tags: cell-biology, dna, apoptosis

I heard that the destination of dying cells is either one of them: Apoptosis and Necrosis. Further I heard that apoptosis causes destroy of cell components and necrosis is caused by autolyses.

But we can do DNA profiling from supposedly dead cells. How is DNA stored in dead cells? Those cells not dead by any chance? Otherwise, the core occasionally remain safe even during such destroy process in Apoptosis or Necrosis?

Comment: In apoptosis, the nucleus falls apart, DNA is fragmented, and cell contents are packaged into vesicles which are then degraded by phagocytes. I suppose there might be fragments of DNA that could be sequenced before phagocytosis occurs.

Comment: @iowf Thank you for the insight. That makes sense to me. Cells are surely dead and destruction process happen but there are many cases that fragmented DNA components remain safe enough to investigate. Now this is my latest understanding.